# \input{file} cannot find figures inside the folder of the file

Tags: input

I have the following directory structure:

```
-main.tex

[folder]

   -input.tex

   -figure1.pdf

   -figure2.pdf
```

I put input1.tex into main.tex but it can't find the figures included directly into input.tex. For instance input.tex that includes figure1.pdf looks like this:

```
\includegraphics{figure1.pdf}
```

Is there any method to let LaTeX know where the files are, or should I rewrite every times the includegraphics:

```
\includegraphics{folder/figure1.pdf}
```

Comment: You could add `\graphicspath{{folder}}` so that you only need `\includegraphics{figure1}`

Comment: Or use the `subfiles` package or whatever it's called. But `\graphicspath` is simpler.